# Converting a Variant (Integer) parameter to Variant (Long)

Tags: vba, type-conversion

I have a Variant parameter passed to a function, and this parameter is essentially an Integer:

```
Function Foo(vNum As Variant) As Long

vNum = 50000
```

When I call this function using:

```
Dim A As Integer
A = 2000
Foo(A)
```

I get an Overflow error (6).

This seems to have something to do with vNum being 'classed' as an integer variant when I pass a number smaller than 32767 (the upper limit of integers), which then causes overflow when attempting to assign a number larger than 32767.

---

My question is, **how do I cast or convert this 'Integer' Variant into one that will accept Longs**?

I tried casting: `vNum = CLng(50000)` and `vNum = CVar(50000)`,

and using dummy variables:

```
Function Foo(vNum As Variant) As Long

Dim vTest As Variant
vTest = 50000
vNum = vTest
```

All of these still generated an Overflow error (6).

Would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you using `vb.net`? _The Variant data type is not supported in Visual Basic .NET_

Comment: Seems like it's vba, not vb.net...sorry I'm very new to vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just define your function like this:

```
Function Foo(ByVal vNum As Variant) As Long
```

If you don't specify ByVal, your parameter is passed ByRef, and any operation you make to the parameter is made on the "original" variable, hence an integer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that they were all passed by reference. I gather from this answer that what I was trying to do actually isn't possible unless A is declared as a Long instead?

Comment: As a general safety measure, you'd better forget the idea of modifying the passed variables, unless it is clearly intended and made to work with ByRef.

Answer (score 0):

If you just set vNum as a Long you dont get that problem.
Then it can contain a number to  2,147,483,648

```
Function Foo(vNum As Long) As Long
    'do stuff
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, but this wouldn't have worked in my case as the function is actually used in COM and therefore (from what I understand) requires Variant parameters.